# How to locate all rows of a pandas data frame where 'date' is in a particular set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of dates in an array called 'signals'. I also have a pandas dataframe, with each row containing a different date's numbers. I want to pull all the 'Adj Close' values from a particular set of dates.

```
signals = buy_signals + sell_signals
signals.sort()
initial_price = df.loc[df['Date'] in signals]['Adj Close']
```

I have tried to use a conditional df.iloc procedure where I check if df['Date'] is in signals, however I get the error: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Use `initial_price = df.loc[df['Date'].isin(signals), 'Adj Close']`

Comment: Please provide either the dataset or enough code to create a portion of the dataframe from your problem so people can help you effectively.